# "Get dependencies" popup not showing android studio for flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Normally when you change something in the "pubspec.yaml" it prompts you with a bar (Image) => [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8qDL.png)
but it wouldnt go away so I pressed "Ignore" and now it refuses to show the popup making it very difficult as I cant get dependencies.

Comment: The way we know that a question has been adequately dealt with is when you accept an answer - either one of the two currently provided if they were sufficient or by you self answering. You don't just edit `(SOLVED)` into the title - especially because you haven't identified *what helped you solve the problem*.

Comment: I'm sorry but it randomly solved itself, and I don't really know the protocol for that.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add a new dependency in your pubspec.yaml file, make sure to install them by running `flutter pub get` in your terminal. To upgrade your dependencies you could simply run `flutter pub upgrade` in your terminal.

Comment: What I meant to say was that when I try adding a new font, image or asset. I am unable use it as I cant press "get dependencies"

Edit: It randomly worked, the miracle of programming.